# Transparent mesh turns other mesh invisible

Tags: mesh, node-editor

[image]
When they do not touch the meshes are fine

[image]
When they do touch the white mesh turns invisible

[image]
Here are the nodes, I've tried different versions but those versions cause a black outline

In normal view it looks like it is fine but when in render mode this happens.

Comment: Texture the exact part of the original mesh instead of using a different object or use a Shrinkwrap modifier - 1st option is better for sure.

Comment: @JanMatys I tried skrinkwrapping but it didn't work. I will try to Texture it.

Comment: So? Wrapping in this case will need A LOT of polys so the texturing is much better.